Working on a dataframe without loading it into memory
I have a dataframe with slightly more than half a million rows. The columns hold very small values, so the dataframe is easily stored in memory.
However on the other hand, I have around 700GB of data, spread into 50-row chunks of binary files, corresponding to each row of my dataframe. So given a row from my small-sized dataframe, I'm able to access the corresponding column value from the 700GB "dataset".
What I want to do is to create one single CSV file from all of these and some additional data that I will produce for each row.
For context, here's the access function and the generator function that I've coded for retrieving a column value from my 700GB data set given a row index:
filenames = os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/ProteiNNGO_Data/") # The folder that has the chunks
def get_embedding_chunk(index, old_chunk_start):
  # The chunks are stored with this name pattern, including the start and end indices
  pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:embeddingsssss_|featuress_)(\d+)_(\d+)$')
  for filename in filenames:
    match = pattern.match(filename)
    if match:
      start, end = int(match.group(1)), int(match.group(2))
      # If we are accessing data that is in the same chunk as before, don't load it again
      if start == old_chunk_start:
        return None, start

      # Otherwise, if we're in the right chunk, load the chunk
      if start <= index < end:
        with open(f"/content/drive/MyDrive/ProteiNNGO_Data/{filename}", "rb") as f:
          return pickle.load(f), start

And here's a generator that I coded that will efficiently iterate over rows
def embedding_generator():
  chunk = None
  start = -1
  for i in range(len(sequences)):
    new_chunk, new_start = get_embedding_chunk(i, start)
    start = new_start
    if new_chunk is not None:
      del chunk
      chunk = new_chunk
    offset = i - start
    yield i, chunk[offset]
    gc.collect()

How can I use this iterator and add each row to a dataframe without having the entire dataframe in the memory?

Check the dask project: https://www.dask.org/

by default python comes with sqlite for such tasks, but as recommended you might want to use dask for better integration with pandas.

Thanks for the recommendation. The problem with dask is, as you could see from my problem I naturally have to work with positional indexing. Dask apparently does not support that. Is there a workaround about this?

For this specific task, I ended up using SQLite, as mentioned by @ahmed-aek.
@jsbueno mentioned Dask, but the way I structured the data required me to use positional indices which Dask does not support.
